# Seeking Europe shapefile with boundaries

Tags: data, europe

Where can I find a simple shapefile or Geopackage file for Europe with boundaries?

Answer (score 3):

Here you will find data in `SHP`, `GEOJSON`, `GDB`, `TOPOJSON` and `SVG` https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units/countries